# When a computer wakes from sleep mode, does it use the same physical addresses as before?

Tags: linux, windows, sleep, ram

When a computer wakes from sleep mode, does it use the same physical addresses as before?
Just curious about this one. I'd assume it could be since it suspends to memory.

Is it possibly also OS-dependent? If so, how does it work for specific operating systems such as Windows or Linux. And, what about the hibernate mode?

Comment: whats a computer physical address?

Comment: If it uses the same physical RAM addresses for its running programs after wake.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAM itself stays in the same place (assuming no one hot-plugged or hot-unplugged any of the memory, of course) - it's organization is decided by the BIOS or whatever boot-process non-PC based systems use.

The term "sleep" usually means "suspend to RAM", which basically means just the processor stops running. Since the processor is the only[1] thing that can re-arrange what goes where in the memory, and it isn't powered during the sleep, it's likely that the RAM doesn't get changed during that time. That's not to say that for example some drivers are told "you're going to sleep, please shut yourself down" and "you're now waking up, please initialize yourself", and in these steps frees and allocates physical memory.

The term "hibernate" usually means "suspend to disk", the memory is written to disk, and I believe that this is done based on the virtual address of the memory, not physical addresses. The process of suspending pretty much resembles what happens when part of a process is swapped out, and when it's restored memory is at least sometimes allocated "fresh".